# C++, most efficient way to change uppercase to lowercase and vice versa without condition branching

Tags: c++, ascii

We have single character `Chr` on input. Output must be lowercase of `Chr` if `Chr` is uppercase and vice versa.

Trivial realization using `if else` statement:

```
if(Chr>='a' && Chr<='z') cout<<(unsigned char)(a-32);
else cout<<(unsigned char)(a+32);
```

Could you propose solution without any condition branching?

Something like `Chr + 32*(<sign of>(Chr - 'a'))`?

**Update**: I kept ASCII in mind when asked this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your characters are using the ASCII character set you can xor with the value 32 to flip between upper and lower case.

```
char switchCase(char letter)
{
    return letter ^ 32;
}
```

Comment: In ASCII indeed you can, and is a clever way of doing it. (If you mention this restriction I think this will get a lot of upvotes.)

Comment: This only works if the input is an alphabetical character, but not for punctuation, digits, etc. But if that is indeed the case, then it's great.

Comment: A(41): 0100,0001 vs a(61): 0110,0001. So the bit 5(32) is the switch. ASCII is so beautiful.

Comment: @ChenOT: But EBCDIC looks prettier on punched cards ;-)

Answer (score 5):

You'll probably find it hard to beat `::tolower` as that will be highly optimised to your platform.

But if you want to handcode it yourself, then maintain an array `arr` of size 256 (based around an `unsigned char`) such that

`arr[n]` is the lower case form of `n`.

That's O(1) with no branching, and will be portable if you set the array up using `'a'`, `'b'`, &c.

Comment: Actually branching and array based are both O(1), although depending on the compiler optimizations, where the coded is placed (loops?) and cache state, the array solution may be slightly slower due to cache faults, while branching may be optimized, for example, using branch predication. As it is usually recommended, test all solutions and profile them to see which one best work for you.

Comment: @cbuchart: Absolutely! Which is why my first sentence probably wins it.

Comment: Considering `tolower` doesn't seem to get inlined (at least on linux clang), the LUT option is likely a win, actually. Not only that, but `tolower` may have to check for locale stuff, though I'm not sure about this one.